# Is it possible to animate the transition between background-size: contain and background-size: cover?

Tags: css, css-transitions

I know it's possible to animate the transition between `background-size` when using pixel or percentage values using css3, but I can't get it working to animate between `contain` and `cover`. (I'm using webkit - chrome and safari)

I have made a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/59Bhb/3/ that shows it working for percentage values, but not contain/cover.

Is it just not supported?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's just not supported - [list of properties you can animate](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-properties)

Comment: But if you check my fiddle, you can see it working if I use percentage.

Comment: Actually, `background-size` is listed as animatable by Gecko in the issue note below the table. Why it doesn't work with `contain` and `cover` is beyond me - I'm guessing they haven't had the chance to write and/or test it yet.

Comment: I meant it doesn't support non-numeric transitions. Yet.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 0):

You can animate it like such in jQuery

$('myElement').animate({'background-size':'whatever size'}, 1000);

but it's difficult to get the desired result as to it resizes linear left-top to down-right regardless of positioning. I've tried putting this in a cms template but it didn't give me the effect I was looking for. Hope I helped